# All monomials in $x_1,x_2$ of degree at most 4

Tags: polynomials

I need to find all monomials in  $x_1,x_2$ of degree at most 4.

I know I should have 15 of them  because  $ {2+4 \choose 4} = 15  $ but I can find only 14

$ 1,x_1,x_1^2,x_1^3,x_1^4,x_2,x_2^2,x_2^3,x_2^4,x_1x_2, x_1x_2^2, x_1x_2^3, x_1^2x_2^2, x_1^3x_2    $

What did I miss here ? is 0 counted as well ?

Comment: Where did ${6 \choose 4}$ come from?

Comment: Given by the professor

Comment: The last one is easily found by listing all pairs $(m,n)$ such that $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers that add up to at most $4$.

Comment: So 0 is counted ?

Comment: Given two **variables** $x_1$ and $x_2$, are there non-negative integer values for $m$ and $n$ such that $x_1^mx_2^n$ equals zero?

Comment: $x_1^{2}x_2$ - I set it out in a table with the columns being powers of $x_1$ and the rows of $x_2$

Comment: You're missing ${x_1}^2 x_2.$

Comment: I  missed that - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion for finding them systematically.  First consider the polynomials in 1 variable (for ease of notation relabeling them $x$ and $y$.)
$x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4$

Now,  to each of these $x^n$, we can multiply by $y^s$, where $0\leq s\leq 4-n$.  So in the first column, you can multiply $x^0$ by anywhere from $y^0$ through $y^4$,    whereas $x^4$ you can only multiply by $y^0$.   As you can see, this gives us the expected 5+4+3+2+1=15 total results

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion for finding them somewhat systematically: list them by degree.

Degree $0$: $1$.

Degree $1$: $x_1,\ x_2$.

Degree $2$: $x_1^2,\ x_1 x_2,\ x_2^2$.

Degree $3$: $x_1^3,\ x_1^2 x_2,\ x_1 x_2^2,\ x_2^3$.

Degree $4$: $x_1^4,\ x_1^3 x_2,\ x_1^2 x_2^2,\ x_1 x_2^3,\ x_2^4$.

Note how for every degree $D$ the monomials are enumerated as $x_1^{D-k} x_2^k$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots,D.$ This works great when there are two variables. When there are more variables one has to extend the method.